# Bootstrap datepicker and popover with dynamically created data

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I am trying to implement popover in to bootstrap datepicker with a dynamically created data. I have different price for each of the day and would like to show as popover.

So far, I am able to return the each price from datepicker's `beforeShowDay` function but since it is not a global variable I can not access this data in popover. Here what I mean;

Datepicker;

```
var checkin = $('#from').datepicker({
                format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
                startDate: '+1d',
                weekStart: 1,
                language: "<%= params[:locale] %>",
                beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                    var ahora = new Date();
                    if (date >= ahora.setHours(0,0,0,0) ) {
                    var date_real = date.getFullYear() + '-' + ( '0' + (date.getMonth()+1) ).slice( -2 ) + '-' + ( '0' + (date.getDate()) ).slice( -2 )


                    for(var l = 0; l < length; l++){
                        //console.log(date_real)
                        //console.log(schedules[l].date)
                        var pop_price;
                        if(schedules[l].date === date_real && schedules[l].price !== ""){
                            //console.log(schedules[l].price);
                            pop_price = schedules[l].price;
                            break;
                        }
                        else{
                            // console.log(basePrice);
                         pop_price = basePrice;

                        }
                    }
                    console.log(pop_price); //here I can get each day's price, either base price or custom price.
                    };


                //finishes here

                    dmy = date.getDate() + "/" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "/" + date.getFullYear();
                    if ($.inArray(dmy, closed_formatted) == -1) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                },
                autoclose: true
            }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
});
```

Then comes the popover;

```
$('body').on({
    mouseenter: function() {


      $(this).popover({
        placement: 'top',
        container: '.datepicker',
        content: 'Demo', // here I have to put pop_price 
      }).popover('show');
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
      $(this).popover('hide')
    }
  }, '.datepicker .day:not(.disabled)');
```

So in `content` instead of writing demo, I have to show the pop_price variable for each of the day.

Comment: Declare a global variable and store the `pop_price` value in the global variable and refer that var in popover

Comment: I think I have to use array or smth because the calendar displays one month. Then each day should return its price either custom or base price

Comment: if you want to declare a global variable from inside a function you need to use the window object else not required, You can store as an array or an object just based on how you would like to use it.